# Advanced Redirect 301 htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, 301-redirect

I need through redirect 301 htaccess this:

Of these:

```
https://ejemplo.com/post-noticia/octubre-2019/122-nombre-de-mi-noticia
```

To this:

```
https://ejemplo.com/noticia/nombre-de-mi-noticia
```

I have tried this:

```
Redirect 301 /post-noticia/octubre-2019/ https://ejemplo.com/noticia/
```

But the result is:

```
https://ejemplo.com/noticia/122-nombre-de-mi-noticia
```

I need the result to be:

```
https://ejemplo.com/noticia/nombre-de-mi-noticia
```

That is, omit: 122-

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried `Redirect 301 /post-noticia/octubre-2019/122- https://ejemplo.com/noticia/`?

If `122-` is a variable (you haven't gave a clue), you have to use either [RedirectMatch](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch) which accepts regexps:

```
RedirectMatch 301 "/post-noticia/octubre-2019/\d+-(.+)$" "https://ejemplo.com/noticia/$1"
```

or fiddle with [mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

Comment: So is. 122- is variable. It works perfect.